# JSF2: Handling RMI Connection from WebListener to ManagedBeans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

[Initial Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606568/jsf2-how-to-initiate-services-at-deployment)

Hi,

I use a @WebListener Class to initiate a RMI connection at application deployment. That connects my JSF frontend with a backend.

That works fine!

Next I want to hand the connection to a ManagedBean because I want to use the connection to e.g. save something out of a bean, since weblistener is not accessible out of xhtml pages.

I tried to put a managedProperty into that class but I think that's not allowed. So how to do that?

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

public static final String SERVER_NAMING = "xxx";
public static final String SERVER_HOST = "xxx"; 

public static FrontendCommInterface server;


public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    try {

        server = (FrontendCommInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://" + SERVER_HOST + "/" + SERVER_NAMING); 
            System.out.println("Connection successfull!");
//HERE THE SERVER SHOULD HANDED TO ANOTHER MANAGEDBEAN !!! BUT HOW TO DO THAT??? 

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.print("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.print("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        System.out.print("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the bean and put in application scope yourself.

```
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("communication", new Communication(server));
```

Comment: I can use ManagedProperties in WebListners?

Comment: No, definitely not. Note that I updated the answer since I misunderstood the initial problem due to lack of coffee this early morning ;)

Comment: No problem :-D. But in the meantime I tried to add your other advice that included postConstruct and it works :-) Thank you